# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "step_images" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, database-migration, rails-migrations

On migration I get the following error message:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "step_images" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"step_images"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"step_images"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum
```

in db
class CreateStepImages < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  def change
    create_table :step_images do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.attachment :image1
      t.attachment :image2
      t.attachment :image3
      t.attachment :image4
      t.attachment :image5
      t.references :steptation, index: true

      t.timestamps 
    end
  end
end
```

in step_image model

```
class StepImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :steptation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in steptation model

```
  has_many :step_images
```

in step_images controller

```
class StepImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_step_image ,only:[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]
  before_action :set_steptation, only: [:new, :create]
   def new
    @steptation =Steptation.find(params[:id])
    @step_image = @steptation.step_images.build
    @user = current_user
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    @step_image = Step_image.new(step_image_params)
    @step_image.user_id = current_user.id
    if @step_image.save
      @steptation.step_images << @step_image 
      redirect_to case_path(id: @steptation.case_id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 

  def edit
  end

  def update

    if @step_image.update(step_image_params)
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "steptation Information updated successfully"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Couldn't update!"
      render :edit
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @step_image.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "step_image deleted Successfully"
  end 

private
  def set_steptation
    @steptation = Steptation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_step_image
    @step_image = Step_image.find(params[:id])
  end

  def step_image_params
    params.require(:step_image).permit(:text,:image1,:image2,:image3,:image4,:image5)
  end
end
```

I did `rake db:rollback STEP=1`

```
$ rake db:rollback STEP=1
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateStepImages (20201119214001)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
== 20201119214001 CreateStepImages: reverting =================================
-- drop_table(:step_images)
   (10.3ms)  DROP TABLE "step_images"
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "step_images" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "step_images"
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:127:in `drop_table'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:499:in `block in revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1022:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `down'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:935:in `move'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:812:in `rollback'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "step_images" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "step_images"
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:127:in `drop_table'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:499:in `block in revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1022:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `down'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:935:in `move'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:812:in `rollback'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "step_images" does not exist
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:127:in `drop_table'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:499:in `block in revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:498:in `revert'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1069:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1022:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `block in migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `each'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:980:in `migrate'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `down'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:935:in `move'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:812:in `rollback'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: make sure you have ran the migrations. `rake db:migrate`

Comment: @SampatBadhe I did. still the same error

Comment: @nourza see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `rake db:migrate`, rails will load the full application code before executing the migrations. Therefore, when you have already defined the `StepImage` class, rails will try to find the corresponding table. However, at this point in time, the table has not yet been created, which then causes this error. Try to comment out the `StepImage` class and everything associated with it (e.g. by moving the files out of the project folder) and re-run the migration. If it works, move the files back.

It seems like the rollback failed for the same reason: the step_images table has never been created. In such cases, I typically do the following:

1. Put the migration content into begin/rescue/end:

   def change
   **begin**
   create_table :step_images do |t|
   t.string :text
   t.attachment :image1
   #...
   end
   **rescue**
   **end**
   end
2. Rollback this migration to get to the original state. The rescue block will catch the error and the migration should succeed.
3. Use psql to check that the step_images table is actually gone. If not, delete it with psql.
4. Sanitize the source code: remove everything that has to do with the new  step_images table. Start with this migration. Move it out of the project, so that `rails c` will not complain about a pending migration. Then move all models, controller, etc. out of the project. Remove all associations pointing to the new model (comment out). Otherwise, relations pointing to non-existing models/tables will cause more errors.
5. Sanitize until `rails c` succeeds in starting the application.
6. Move the migration back into db/migrations and run it.
7. If this succeeds, bring everything back in again. If unsure, do in multiple small steps and check in-between by running `rails c`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After i did what you do I got the same error. I edited my quesrtion. please check the error I got PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "step_images" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "step_images"